# Kendo UI Change data on clicking "Go to next page"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am very new to Kendo and MVC4. I got the piece where I display the data on a Kendo Grid on my webpage. [image: Grid]

On a single page, I have enabled only 10 items (rows) to be displayed. But when I click on the  number "2", the page fantastically fails.

[image: failure]

I understand that I am missing some piece of code on the controller side. But due to my lack of knowledge about MVC4, I dont know what to add at what place. Below is the View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<MVC4Trial.Models.vwCallDetail>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Call Detail View</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CCCID).Width(50).Title("CCCID");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Mp3_Url).Width(50).Title("MP3 URL");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Target_Number).Width(50).Title("Target Number");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Duration).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Index).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LocalTime).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Site_Name___Address).Width(50).Title("Site Address");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Ad_Source_Name).Width(50).Title("Ad Source Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Tracking_Number).Width(50).Title("Tracking Number");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Caller_Number).Width(50).Title("Caller");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Available_Feature).Width(50).Title("Features");
    })
    .Pageable(page => page.Enabled(true).PageSizes(new Int32[] {10, 20, 30, 40}))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.SortMode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("vwCallDetail", "Grid"))
        )
    .Resizable(resize =>resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reordering => reordering.Columns(true))   


    )
```

**Below is the controller code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVC4Trial.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

namespace MVC4Trial.Controllers
{
    public class CallTrackController : Controller
    {
        private CallTrackEntities db = new CallTrackEntities();

        //
        // GET: /CallTrack/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.vwCallDetails.ToList());
        }


        public ActionResult vwCallDetails([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetCallDetails().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<vwCallDetail> GetCallDetails()
        {
            var callDetails = new CallTrackEntities();
            return callDetails.vwCallDetails.Select(vwCallDetail => new vwCallDetail
            {
                CCCID = vwCallDetail.CCCID,
                Mp3_Url = vwCallDetail.Mp3_Url,
                Index = vwCallDetail.Index,
                Target_Number = vwCallDetail.Target_Number,
                Duration = vwCallDetail.Duration,
                LocalTime = vwCallDetail.LocalTime,
                Site_Name___Address = vwCallDetail.Site_Name___Address,
                Ad_Source_Name = vwCallDetail.Ad_Source_Name,
                Tracking_Number = vwCallDetail.Tracking_Number,
                Caller_Number = vwCallDetail.Caller_Number,
                Available_Feature = vwCallDetail.Available_Feature


            });
        }


        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            vwCallDetail vwcalldetail = db.vwCallDetails.Find(id);
            if (vwcalldetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vwcalldetail);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CallTrack/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /CallTrack/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(vwCallDetail vwcalldetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.vwCallDetails.Add(vwcalldetail);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(vwcalldetail);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CallTrack/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            vwCallDetail vwcalldetail = db.vwCallDetails.Find(id);
            if (vwcalldetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vwcalldetail);
        }

        //
        // POST: /CallTrack/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(vwCallDetail vwcalldetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(vwcalldetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(vwcalldetail);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CallTrack/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            vwCallDetail vwcalldetail = db.vwCallDetails.Find(id);
            if (vwcalldetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vwcalldetail);
        }

        //
        // POST: /CallTrack/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            vwCallDetail vwcalldetail = db.vwCallDetails.Find(id);
            db.vwCallDetails.Remove(vwcalldetail);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the _Layout.cshtml file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Kendo UI Sample</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.default.min.css")">
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
         <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.min.js")"></script>
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <div class="float-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>

        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Now what changes do I need to make to the View/Model/Controller to make this thing work? Please forgive me if I have omitted any details. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to look at the [Telerik's online demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)

You must write your controller:

```
    public ActionResult vwCallDetail([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(db.TableName.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

I hope you've included these files in the view:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: do I also need to change my jscript by any chance?

Comment: Did you include the above js files in the view?

Comment: Yes. I have the js files included on the _Layout.cshtml file.

Comment: I followed the same demo, but it does not give any information about going to the next page or so

Comment: It doesn't require anything. Because your grid works in Ajax mode, the above action in the controller will do the paging.

Comment: Ok. I will try it out and report back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added the controller as well, but again there is no effect. What am I missing? Do you need to look at any other piece of code?

Comment: Yes, your controller and view

Comment: Added the controller and the view code as well to the question.

Comment: It seems that your codes are correct. Could you please show the layout?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your comment yesterday. It seems that everything is alright. Are the scripts being load on the page?